# using d_ff in always block

Tags: verilog

I want to make a counter like gray code but this is different , so write this  code but help me to find an error

This is the code

```
module counter2(mainclk,rst , A,B,C,D );
input mainclk;
input rst;
output A,B,C,D;
reg A,B,C,D;
reg [3:0]qb;

reg anb,dnb,bc,nca,nd,na,nb,cna;
reg ap,bp,cp;
initial
begin
A=1'b0;
B=1'b1;
C=1'b0;
D=1'b1;

qb[3]=1'b1;
qb[2]=1'b0;
qb[1]=1'b1;
qb[0]=1'b0;

end
always @(posedge mainclk )
begin
    if(rst)
        begin
            A<=1'b0;
            B<=1'b1;
            C<=1'b0;
            D<=1'b1;
        end
    else
        begin
            anb <= A && qb[2];
            dnb <= D && qb[2];
            ap <=  anb || dnb;
            d_ff dffa(ap , 0 , mainclk , A ,qb[3]);
            bc <= B && C ;
            nca <= A && qb[1];
            bp <= bc || nca;
            @d_ff dffb(bp , 0 , mainclk , B ,qb[2]);
            cp <= qb[0] || qb[3] || qb[2] ;
            @d_ff dffc(cp , 0 , mainclk , C ,qb[1]);
            cna <= C && qb[3];
            @d_ff dffd(cna , 0 , mainclk , D ,qb[0]);
        end
end

endmodule
```

and the error is `Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at counter2.v(37) near text "dffa";  expecting "<=", or "="`

Comment: Where is line 37? It's no fun to manually count source lines! Your code has no comments, just cryptic signal names.

Answer (score 1):

Erm, your `d_ff` module is a self contained unit, it will contain an `always` block. You instantiate the module separately (i.e. not in an `always` block), and use `wire` for all the outputs and `reg or wire` for all the inputs.

Once you connect up `mainclk` to the clock input of your `d_ff` module and also `rst`, then it will behave as a flip flop synchronous to all those in your `always` block.

---

You don't have to stick everything in the same `always` block, you can have as many as you need. Any that have the same edge sensitivity list will be synchronous to each other regardless of whether or not they are in the same block.